# Docker Swarm update Service with host network

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm, docker-network, docker-stack

I have a docker swarm with currently just one node and a few stacks. To be able to get the ip-address of the client requesting one of my services I switched the port on one service to mode:host. This works fine except when I want to update that service. I didn't change the deploy-order so it should be the default 'stop-first' but when I use `stack deploy` the tasks failes with the following message:

```
no suitable node (host-mode port already in use on 1 node)
```

When I scale down the service to 0 and then use `stack deploy` it works without problem but I don't understand why it becomes a problem when updating directly. Shouldn't "stop-first" mean, that the old service is killed first (freeing up the port) and then the new service is started?
How can I change the yml without having to scale to 0 before deploying the change?

this is the application.yml in question:

```
version: "3.7"

services:
  myservice:
    image: myrepo/gateway
  ports:
    - mode: host
      protocol: tc
      published: 443
      target: 443
  networks:
    - gateway_net

networks:
  gateway_net:
    external: true # was created with 'docker network create -d overlay gateway_net', is used to connect gw with other services
```